# How to pass two parameters in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to pass in two parameters in the line `PFCloud...`. The code works when I just implement `"token":myVal` for the `withParameters` parameter, but doesn't work when I try to add `useremail` as well. I would like to know how I can do so.

```
var useremail = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("username") as! String
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("customer", withParameters: ["token":myVal] && ["email":useremail], block: { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Comment: like this? ["token": myVal, "email": useremail]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Parameters` is of type `Dictionary`. To add an element to a `Dictionary`, you need to separate the key-value pairs with a comma.

So instead of:

```
["token":myVal] && ["email":useremail]
```

You want:

```
["token":myVal, "email":useremail]
```

Because:

```
["token":myVal] && ["email":useremail]
```

Will be an expression of type `Bool` and not of type `Dictionary`.